# Count Function on Multiple Columns by Date (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, count, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 and trying to do multiple counts on different columns and can't figure out how to get it to work properly.  I have two queries that work independently, but having trouble when trying to combine them.  Trying to count the number of tickets opened and closed during each individual date while passing through an @StartDate and @EndDate.

For example, here's my first query: (we assign certain codes to differentiate between different reasons tickets are created, just wanted to throw that out there in case that line creates any confusion.  Also our dates are datetime format, hence the use of CAST)

```
SELECT 
Cast(CreateDate AS Date) AS 'Date',
Count(CreateDate) AS '# Created'

FROM dbo.Tickets

WHERE 
Cast(CreateDate AS Date) >= @StartDate and 
Cast(CreateDate AS Date) <=@EndDate and
(Reason >= 36 and Reason <= 41 OR Reason = 17)

GROUP BY Cast(CreateDate AS Date)

ORDER BY 'Date'
```

Which yields the following results:

```
Date             # Created
----------       -------------
5/1/2013         396
5/2/2013         418
5/3/2013         288
5/4/2013         28
5/5/2013         100
```

My second query is the exact same as the "Create Date" query, just replaced with "Resolved Date" wherever "CreateDate" is located.  However, there were no tickets resolved on the date 5/4/2013.

How can I combine these two queries into one, and get it to return a result set like below?

```
 Date             # Created           # Resolved
----------       -------------        -------------
5/1/2013         396                  400
5/2/2013         418                  322
5/3/2013         288                  280
5/4/2013         28                   0 
5/5/2013         100                  11
```

I think the part that is throwing me off is that there is no resolved date of 5/4/2013 in the table.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
with all_dates(the_date)
as
(
    select min(cast(createdate as date))
    from tickets
    UNION ALL
    select DATEADD(day,1,the_date)
    from all_dates
    where all_dates.the_date < GETDATE()+1

)

select the_date,
        SUM(case when CAST(t.createdate as DATE) = ad.the_date then 1 else 0 end) as CreatedCount,
        SUM(Case when CAST(t.resolveddate as DATE) = ad.the_date then 1 else 0 end) as ResolvedCount
from all_dates ad
left outer join tickets t 
on ad.the_date = CAST(t.createdate as DATE)
or ad.the_date = CAST(t.resolveddate as DATE)
group by ad.the_date
option (MAXRECURSION 10000)
```

I created a CTE to hold all of the dates between the 1st created date and today.  This way, even if you don't have a ticket created or resolved on a date you will still see that day in your results.

Comment: You need to cast the dates in the `CASE`s just like you did in the `ON` clause.

Comment: Yes I do.  Thanks.  Edit made.

Comment: Awesome!  I got it working perfectly!! Thanks so much for the help!  Didn't even think to use a CTE :)

Comment: Awesome!  Happy to help.  And thanks to HABO for pointing out my error.